# How to create glyph for "rewind" with dynamic value for the seconds in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

**Problem:**

i am using font awesome to create a glyph for rewind. I'd like to add a number inside it like so:

[image]

I dont want to create a hardcoded image as I'd like the number inside to be configurable/dynamic.

Here is what I've done so far (which is not much).

**Code:**

```
<i class="fa fa-undo fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-history fa-5x"></i>
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/un9ds33r/

FWIW I can use jQuery in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible layout for you:

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon .number {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-undo fa-5x"></i><span class="number">5</span></span>
```